# .htaccess denying $_GET params

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-routing

Basically, I'd like to pass a $_GET param like that:

`<a class="btn btn-danger" href="/deleteController.php?delete=<?= $tasks['listid'] ?>"> Delete </a>`

However, it seems that my .htaccess file does not see it as a valid file:

```
Warning: require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/src/controller/deleteController.php?delete=1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/public/index.php on line 14

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/src/controller/deleteController.php?delete=1' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/public/index.php on line 14
```

And finally my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [L]
</IfModule>
```

If someone could help me figuring out how can I get my .htaccess to allow $_GET params, and still requiring the wanted file, I'd greatly appreciate it.

## EDIT:

index.php controller (before the fix):

```
$uri = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

   if ($uri === '' || $uri === '/' || $uri === '/index.php') {
       $uri = '/task_list_Controller.php';
   }
   require_once(CONTROLLER_PATH . $uri);
```

Comment: please add index.php contents to Your question, since solution to Your problem could not exist without seeing index.php file. (which obviously found in Your github repo, which has pull request from me)

Comment: @num8er done. tks for the help

Comment: don’t put Your solution in Your question. You’re violating Q&A format of StackOverflow. Please add Your solution as an answer. It will help people quickly find solution.

Comment: @num8er Fixed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem not related to Apache.

```
Warning: 
require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/src/controller/deleteController.php?delete=1): 
failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/public/index.php on line 14

Fatal error: 
require_once(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/src/controller/deleteController.php?delete=1'
```

You're trying to `require_once(.../deleteController.php?delete=1)` which of course will not exist, since the file `deleteController.php?delete=1` does not exist. 
there is only `deleteController.php`.

[image: github]

In file `/opt/lampp/htdocs/public/index.php` on line 14 I saw that You're requiring file by `CONTROLLER_PATH.$uri`.

So the problem comes from line 9 where You're passing uri with query string.

simply write it like this:

```
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);

if ($uri === '' || $uri === '/' || $uri === '/index.php') {
   $uri = '/task_list_Controller.php';
}

if (is_file(CONTROLLER_PATH . $uri)) {
  require_once(CONTROLLER_PATH . $uri);
}
```